# Unidentified function 'CONCAT' in expression

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using Microsoft access for a school project and am trying to the following:

"Change the EmployeeID text box to a combo box. The row source should be
an SQL statement that displays from the Employees table the EmployeeID and
LastName, Firstname both in a single column"

The following is the SQL code that I wrote

```
SELECT CONCAT(EmployeeID, ' - ', LastName, ', ', FirstName) AS EmployeeFullName
FROM Employees
ORDER BY EmployeeID;
```

When trying to run this, I get the error "Unidentified function 'CONCAT' in expression". Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Access does not have a `CONCAT()` function. String concatenation is done using `&`.

```sql
SELECT EmployeeID & ' - ' & LastName & ', ' & FirstName AS EmployeeFullName
FROM Employees
ORDER BY EmployeeID;
```